comparison of two array
I am testing a scenario in Cypress however when I get to compare two arrays at the end of the scenario, the code fails.
This is the code where I have a pre-defined array and i want to create the second array. The code fails at the last line saying the second array is an object (I guess somehow I am comparing an array to an object?):
cy.get(desiredCEXs).then( list => { cy.get(expectedCEXnames).should('have.all.members', list)})
I'm very new to Cypress. So, I was wondering how I could fix the code? I thought by using .push() , I am constructing the second array. This is the link to where I am asserting the code  https://www.coingecko.com/en/coins/kira-network
Then ('I assert what exchnages KIRA Network is listed on', ()=>
{
    const desiredCEXs = [ 'Gate.io', 'AscendEX (BitMax)', 'Uniswap V2 (Ethereum)', 'Gate.io' ]
    const expectedCEXnames = []
    cy.get('tbody').eq(4).find('tr').as('exchanges')
    cy.get('@exchanges').each( eachExchange =>
    {
        var exTypeText = eachExchange.children('td').eq(2).children('span').children('div').text().trim()
        var exName = eachExchange.children('td').eq(1).children('div').children('a').children('div').text().trim()
        if(exTypeText == 'CEX')
        {
            expectedCEXnames.push(exName)
        }
    })
    .then( () =>
    {
        console.log(expectedCEXnames)
    })
    cy.get(desiredCEXs).then( list => { cy.get(expectedCEXnames).should('have.all.members', list)})
})


The exact way you do it depends if you require ordering check as well as existence check.
For checking existence each value (any order)
const desiredCEXs = [ 'Gate.io',...]
cy.get('tbody').eq(4).find('tr').each(eachExchange => {
  const exName = ...
  if(exTypeText == 'CEX') {
    const isInList = desiredCEXs.includes(exName)

    assert(isInList, `${exName} is in the list`)
    // or
    expect(isInList).to.be.ok
    // or
    cy.wrap(exName).should('be.oneOf', desiredCEXs)
  })
})

For order checking as well as existence, use deep.eq to check both arrays
const desiredCEXs = [ 'Gate.io',...]
const actualCEXs = []
cy.get('tbody').eq(4).find('tr').each(eachExchange => {
  const exName = ...
  if(exTypeText == 'CEX') {
    actualCEXs.push(exName)
  })
})
.then(() => {
  cy.wrap(actualCEXs)).should('deep.eq', desiredCEXs)  // note "deep" for array check
})

Other notes

cy.get() is for elements not variables
you don't need .as('exchanges')

